# Error encountered when using OrderBy and Skip in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I coded a query on entity like this:

```
public List<Cliente> ListarClienteCobrancaPaginado(string args, int take, int skip)
{          
       var list = from cliente in _clienteRepositorio.UnitOfWork.QueryableFor<Cliente>()
                  join conta in _clienteRepositorio.UnitOfWork.QueryableFor<MovimentacaoConta>()
                      on cliente.PessoaId equals conta.PessoaId
                  where (conta.MovimentacoesContaParcelas.Any(p => p.DataVencimentoReal.Value > DateTime.Now) 
                           && cliente.Pessoa.Nome.ToLower().StartsWith(args.ToLower()))
                     || (conta.MovimentacoesContaParcelas.Any(p => p.DataPagamento.Value == null) 
                           && cliente.Pessoa.Nome.ToLower().StartsWith(args.ToLower()))
                  select cliente;

        return list.Include(p=>p.Pessoa)
                   .OrderBy(x=>x.Pessoa.Nome)
                   .Distinct()
                   .Skip(skip)
                   .Take(take)
                   .ToList();
}
```

and i'm getting this error message:

> The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.

but I'm already calling `OrderBy` before `Skip` in my query.

Can someone help me?

Comment: the answer is in the error message

Comment: Whoah, now that's some rage-downvoting. The funny part is - it's not that stupid question if you actually look, that he IS calling `orderby` before `skip`. What he didn't know is that `Distinct` is trashing the order, which is not that obvious for a newbie and is not implied by the error message. But hey, I guess on SO we're too pro to care about actually reading someone's code, right? On the other hand: richer description of the problem would change users attitude aswell.

Comment: @Tarec Agree that the question is not that bad, but it was poorly worded. I edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: sorry for my english! I'm a brazilian dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `OrderBy` after `Distinct`. `Distinct` will destroy the order of your collection (making the `OrderBy` call useless) and hence `Skip` will not work, as the error message tells you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

I got two solutios.

First by myself adding a method .AsEnumerable() after .include()
The other one is to change positon of  the method .orderby() with .distinct().

Thanks the community for the attention.

Comment: Note that when you call .AsEnumerable() after .Include(), you'll do the ordering/dictinct/skip/take-stuff in memory after loading the data from the database, while otherwise this is done by the database before loading the data into the application memory.